# Mongoose: Update by pushing an object in an array

Tags: arrays, mongoose

This is the model I am working with:

```
name: {
  type: String
},
payment: {
  id: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  cards: [
    {
      id: {
        type: String
      },
      is_default: {
        type: Boolean,
        "default": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to add a card to the `cards` array, for example:

```coffee
card =
  id: "some_token"
  is_default: true
```

I am using the `update` method to push the card to the array, but it won't add the card to the document. Instead, it creates a new document with only those fields:

```js
{
  id: "some_token",
  is_default: true,
  _id: someId
}
```

Any idea how I can update the actual document I am targeting instead of creating a new document?

Here's my code (using CoffeeScript):

```coffee
update_where =
  payment:
    id: "some_id"
update_push =
  $push:
    'payment.cards':
      id: card_token
      is_default: false

Customer.update update_where, update_push, {upsert: true}, (err, results) ->
  # Do something with the results
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh… I just noticed my mistake. The problem was in the **`where`** statement.
I was doing:

```coffee
payment:
  id: "some_id"
```

But the right thing to write is the following:

```coffee
'payment.id': 'some_id'
```

And it now works!